# Samsung ML-2165 - Are there any installation problems on 12.04 or 12.10?

Tags: printing, compatibility

I am planning to buy one of these printers. The only thing I am afraid of is that it may not be compatible with Ubuntu. Is there anything to be worry about? Do you recommend them?

[Samsung ML-2165](http://www.littlewoodsireland.ie/samsung-ml-2165-20ppm-mono-laser-printer/1143812956.prd)

[Samsung ML-2165W/SEE](http://www.littlewoodsireland.ie/samsung-ml-2165wsee-20ppm-mono-laser-printer/1143813186.prd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the [product support page at samsung.com](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/support/model/ML-2165/XSS-downloads) you see Linux is supported. However, that's a very user unfriendly runnable, so I recommend the [The Samsung Unified Linux Driver Repository](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/) for installing with ease (package repository).

Should just work.

Comment: Having just installed one this weekend, I can confirm that at least ML-2165 (the non-wifi, USB-connected one) works under 12.04.3, with suld-driver-4.01.17 installed from the SULD repository.

Comment: I can confirm CUPS 1.7.2 and suld-driver-4.01.17 on Ubuntu 14.04 Server are working... At least for me. I have ML-2165